# Why does my code not replace the repeatd letters in aardvark and baboon example?

Tags: python

Why does my code not replace the repeated
letters in aardvark and baboon example??
This an exercise for the hangman game !!

```
import random
word_list = ["aardvark", "baboon", "camel"]
chosen_word = random.choice(word_list)

#Testing code
print(f'Pssst, the solution is {chosen_word}.')
display = []
for letter in chosen_word:
       display.append("_")
print(display)
#TODO-1: - Create an empty List called display.
#For each letter in the chosen_word, add a "_" to 'display'.
#So if the chosen_word was "apple", display should be ["_", "_", "_", "_", "_"] with 5 "_" representing each letter to guess.

guess = input("Guess a letter: ").lower()

#TODO-2: - Loop through each position in the chosen_word;
#If the letter at that position matches 'guess' then reveal that letter in the display at that position.
#e.g. If the user guessed "p" and the chosen word was "apple", then display should be ["_", "p", "p", "_", "_"].
for letter in chosen_word:
    if letter == guess:
           index = chosen_word.index(letter)
           display[index] = letter
print(display)
#TODO-3: - Print 'display' and you should see the guessed letter in the correct position and every other letter replaced with "_".
#Hint - Don't worry about getting the user to guess the next letter. We'll tackle that in step 3.`enter code here`
```

Comment: `index = chosen_word.index(letter)` will return you only the index of the first occurance

Comment: maybe look at using `for index, letter in enumerate(chosen_word):` then you dont need to look up the index just do `if letter == guess: display[index] = letter`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`chosen_word.index(letter)` gives you the only the first occurrence of `letter`, so you are replacing a letter at the same position over and over again.

A direct remedy might be to use the second parameter of `index`, which sets the starting position of searching:

```py
current = 0
for letter in chosen_word:
    if letter == guess:
           index = chosen_word.index(letter, current)
           display[index] = letter
           current = index + 1
```

A better one would be to directly get the position of the letter being considered at each iteration, by using `enumerate`:

```py
for index, letter in enumerate(chosen_word):
    if letter == guess:
           display[index] = letter
```

An alternative would be to use list comprehension and `zip`:

```py
display = [y if y == guess else x for x, y in zip(display, chosen_word)]
```